# Is it possible to manually manipulate a css breakpoint in an element (no iframe)?

Tags: html, css, breakpoints, viewport

Here is the problem I have described in 4 bullets:

1. I need to display a "small" Version of a built website as a preview (done) ✅
2. This preview **is not** rendered in an iFrame (its built by vuejs) (also done) ✅
3. The wrapping div is scaled down (scale factor and scale width) (also done) ✅
4. But *here is the thing*: The scale facotr and scale width *does not* affect the grid (col-xs-,...) so all the content is just breaking as the main window is... but I need a "by button click" behaviour ❌

e.g. Click on the Preview as "Mobile" button and the Preview automatically "breaks" responsive....

```
                       Preview as [Mobile] [Tablet] [Desktop]

|--------------------------------------------------------------|
|     Drag Drop Page Builder        |          Preview         |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So I need to pass any value to the wrapping div so the content behaves like it would be displayed on a mobile device, tablet and so on...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where does the `col-xs-` come from? Is it bootstrap?

Comment: yes it is bootstrap @MarteenDev

Comment: no it's not possible - media queries are based on the window size so if you are not changing that, then you will get desktop version rendered all the time.  The only other thing you could do is add a class to your body and then add overrides to make sure the specific class combined with your specified class becomes active (although that would be a whole lot of work and bloat).  Any reason why you don't just shove it in an iframe and resize the iframe?  that way your media queries should kick in

Comment: Thanks @Pete for your reply. For me the reason was, because I need dynamic content and not showing another page

Because the drag and drop page builder is built in Vue JS and renders the content "Live" as soon as you drop anything. And my question then is: Is it possible to dynamically render a content into an iframe with vuejs?